# Kendo Grid toolbar item not firing click function:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have a few items in Kendo Grid Toolbar.

Everything works fine **excepts** last item called "test".

**Click event not firing defined action.**

**Question is:** How to solve that to fire another AngularJS function in the same Controller?

```
 toolbar: [
                { template: kendo.template($("#preparedViewsToolbar").html()) },
                { name: "create" },
                { name: "save" },
                { name: "cancel" },
                {
                    name: "test",
                    text: "testme",
                    click: function(e){
                        console.log("TEST");
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: are you using angular-kendo and if so which version?

Answer (score 3):

This is because Kendo UI does not understand the `click` property on a toolbar item. It is not supported [[reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-toolbar.template)]. Instead, you should define a template for the toolbar item, and in that template you can bind your click function.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/recaxehu/1/edit?html,console,output)

```
<div id="grid"></div>
  <script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <a class="k-button" href="\#" onclick="return toolbar_click()">Command</a>
  </script>
  <script>
  function toolbar_click() {
    console.log("Toolbar command is clicked!");
    return false;
  }
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: [
      { name: 'create' },
      { name: 'save' },
      { name: 'cancel' },
      { template: kendo.template($("#template").html()) }
    ],
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name', field: "name" },
      { title: 'Age', field: "age" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ]
  });
</script>
```

Comment: onclick in not same as ng-click, after onclick you cannot call angular method on scope.

Comment: That's what your other SO question is about. You did not provide any sort of AngularJS implementation, so it's impossible to read your mind. I simply answered how you add a new toolbar item to a Kendo grid, as per the documentation, if you had taken the time to read it.

Answer (score -1):

```
var tableDIV =  $("<div id='grid'> </div>");
$("body").append(tableDIV); 

//set toolbar options and custom events. 
var toolBar = [
    {
        name: "Add",
        text: "Add new record",
        events:{
            click:function(e){
                alert($(this).text());
            }
        }
    }
];

//initialize grid with toolbar options.
tableDIV = tableDIV.kendoGrid({  
    toolbar: toolBar,  
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name', field: "name" },
      { title: 'Age', field: "age" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");  

//now bind events here.  
tableDIV.element.find(".k-header.k-grid-toolbar > a").each(function(i){
    console.log(i,toolBar);
    $(this).bind((toolBar[i].events != undefined ? toolBar[i].events : null));
});
```